# Is the fermi paradox a rational motivator for theism?

Tags: atheism, alien-life

I don't necessarily think that advanced alien life is any more likely than God (maybe not the details of the Bible etc., and I am unfamiliar with the ins and outs of it, but am no creationist etc.). Just my take on that.

Is it *exquisitely* bad reasoning to use the fermi paradox to argue for God?

Comment: Please add a description of the Fermi paradox and explain how you think it could be used to argue for the existence of God. I can't think of how it would.

Comment: God didn't feel like making aliens?